# CPU fails to restart during Win7 re-installation

Tags: windows-7, reboot

A computer was built for my brother and was up and running for a few months. We are not sure what he did but just two days ago, his PC kept shutting down spontaneously. We thought that it was because of an errant registry (due to his downloads) or an abused CPU usage (that overheated). His CPU seems to be working fine. It has a dedicated fan.

He tried re-installing Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) to see if it would solve the problem. The installation seemed fine until it got to the point where a restart was required to continue the process. This is where the problems starts because the computer **does** shut down but fails restart on its own. When I press the power button, a "Windows did not shut down properly" screen appears wherein the user is prompted to choose among various safe modes: safe mode only, safe mode with networking, etc.

What seems to be the problem and how can we solve it? *I have to admit that I am relatively a noob here and I appeal to you gods of computing for help.*

Comment: does safe mode work?

Comment: You just stated that his CPU overheated, so what leads you to believe that it is not damaged? The way that it seems to be acting, it definitely sounds like it could be damaged.

Comment: Also, if your brothers computer was having certain hardware/software problems, it should of happened with a blue screen. You didn't mention anything about a blue screen error, so it sounds like it was just turning off. This makes me think something is wrong with the CPU, or possibly the PSU. Post an edit with the system specs and that could maybe point to an under powered PSU, which is a lot better than a damaged CPU

Comment: @Logman, yes, it does seem to work on safe mode, but this is no option for us as for the fact that we are trying to re-install the operating system.

Comment: @DrZoo No, the CPU was not damaged. It is working perfectly.

Comment: @user8837, then my next guess would be failing PSU or under powered PSU. Also when in safe mode, can you inform us of any warnings, errors or critical errors from the event viewer?

Comment: @user8837 if it works in SafeMode, then more than likely it is a driver problem. You reinstalled Windows, but it is failing after reboot because of this driver issue. Make sure you have all latest correct drivers for all hardware installed, you might have to remove any hardware if not needed like PCI/GFX cards. Run it with minimal hardware.

Comment: It turns out that the culprit was the PSU. A friend of ours who manages a computer repair shop as a business replaced the unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad you figured out the problem, due to PSU instability issues.

**Instability**

- One sign of power problems is system instability under load. This can be a tricky symptom to diagnose, since many different things can cause random errors and crashes. If you can rule out software problems, bad hard drive sectors, and a virus, continued unexplained crashes could point to a power supply failure. You should take special note if the crashes seem to happen more frequently when running CPU- or graphics-intensive programs, since these actions would require more current from the power supply and would be a good indicator of a problem.

For future references, here is more information on [PSU troubleshooting](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/power-supply-protection-calculate-consumption,3066-5.html)